# Proving the $\ell^2$ and $\ell^{\infty}$ norms are well-defined by not equivalent

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

> $$\|x\|_2 := \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} x_i^2}, \quad\quad \|x\|_{\infty} := \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} |x_i|.$$

The space I'm working with is[image: space]

How can I prove the following?

1) how can I show that these two are well-defined? My suggestion for $\|x\|_2$ is that due to the square root it can't be negative, so it has to be well-defined. But what about the other one?

2) I'm supposed to show that they are not equivalent, but I was assuming that they must be?

Comment: What's the space that you're working with?

Comment: my apologies , I forget to mention it. I'm also sorry that I'm not formatting it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first norm is well-defined because, by definition of $\ell^2$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x_n}^2<\infty$ (and, obviously, it's non-negative). The second one is well-defined because, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x_n}^2$ converges, the sequence $\bigl({x_n}^2\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges and therefore the sequence $\bigl(|x_n|\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is bounded.

They are not equivalent because if $X_n\in\ell^2$ is such that the first $n$ terms of $X_n$ are equal to $1$ and all others are equal to $0$, then $\|X_n\|_2=\sqrt n$ and $\|X_n\|_\infty=1$.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, what the space does, the two norms are in that space, correct? Or what does that mean?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Let's say I'd like to show that these two norms are in the space mentioned above. How would I do that?

Comment: That is the same thing as asking whether or not the norms are well-defined, and I proved that they are.